# Downcase words except their first character

Tags: ruby, string

The function `.capitalize` sets the first character of a string to *upcase* and sets all other characters to *downcase*.

**capitalizing every word of a string**

```
"my Name is MARC".split(" ").map{|word| word.capitalize}.join(" ")
# => "My Name Is Marc"
```

I need a similair function where I can *downcase* all characters, **but** leave the first character *untouched*. So every word would get downcased except its first letter would stay the same.

```
"my Name is MARC".some_function
# => "my Name is Marc"
```

Comment: sorry if misleading? how would you put it?

Comment: 1) How is that the opposite of `capitalize`? 2) If you downcase all except the first letter, why do you not get `"My name is marc"`? 3) What is your question? 4) "Basically" as opposed to what? What is the "advanced" part?

Comment: *Basically I am looking for the exact opposite of capitalize.* is misleading with the subject of your post. Totally contradicts with each other,

Comment: opposite of `capitalize`: "aBBB" => "abbb" and "ABBB" => "Abbb". instead of upping the first, down all but first.

Comment: opossite of `Foo Barrrr BAAAZ` what ?

Comment: :) okay, fine. The answers below solves the problem anyhow, can we get on with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Advanced regular expressions: [positive lookbehind](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors)

```
"My name is MARC".gsub(/(?<=\w)\w+/) { |s| s.downcase }
#=> "My name is Marc"
```

Even shorter (as suggested by @falsetru):

```
"My name is MARC".gsub /(?<=\w)\w+/, &:downcase
#=> "My name is Marc"
```

Comment: +1. You can pass `&:downcase` instead of the block: `"My name is MARC".gsub(/(?<=\w)\w+/, &:downcase)`

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expression ([`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub)):

```
"My name is MARC".gsub(/\w+/) { |x| x[0] + x[1..-1].downcase }
# => "My name is Marc"
```

---

```
x[0]: To keep the case of the first letter of each word.
x[1..-1].downcase: To change the case (excpet the first letter)
```

Comment: +1. I accepted @mdesantis answer though as it's a bit shorter. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `titleize` - [here](http://apidock.com/rails/String/titleize) though you I don't know if Marc in your case is an attribute on a model and the string is just in the view.  Kind of confused as you've put the capital on Marc

Comment: with `titleize`I would get `My Name Is Marc`, I am trying to downcase all following CAPS of a word, except the first.

Comment: Then falsetru's answer is the right one.